# How to deal with questions that aren't really "questions"

Tags: discussion, self-answer, community-standards

How do you handle such questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380540/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql?

This particular question was, naturally, closed. But there are numerous times that I have seen this happen on SO. I know [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). But is there a line where we draw a line on what borders on users treating it like their personal blog site and where users ask a legit question only to find their own solution a little later and post that as the solution?

What really prompted me to ask this question was the growing propensity to get into arguments or at times rationalize something that cannot or shouldn't be. A trend mostly seen in newer users. I am know to be sarcastic in my comments at times (I am that in real life too). But never caustic or personal!! Do we just take a step back in such cases? Should we indulge in *hit-and-run* closures? I normally leave a comment when I downvote / vote to close a question. Should I stop doing this for fear of getting obnoxious replies from authors or even [retaliation downvotes - March 11 and 12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450534/siddharth-lele?tab=reputation) (in the question linked at the top)?

What is the general practice followed by the more tenured users in such cases?

Comment: close and delete all off them which are same like this

Comment: Best practice would be to downvote the (non-)question into oblivion and close it.

Comment: Questions that pose no question have no use as you said. I generally try and be as constructive as possible prior to down voting to give them a chance to edit their question.

Comment: @Nashibukasan: I have not said they have no use. In the example, the OP has not posted the solution as a solution. The solution **is** in the OP. Plus the non-rational that followed is the concern. The whole point is that it isn't even a question. It's more like a blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its ok to answer your own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653436/how-to-visual-studio-add-in-manager). Its has to be a good question that will help others.

**The penalty is downvotes &/or closure. That's where you draw the line.**

Obviously it is better etiquette (if you know the answer before hand) to tick the Answer My Own Question TickBox when posting the question:

[image]

When people do answer their own questions I prefer if they make sure the answer is a Community Wiki.

And its polite to let people know in your question that you have posted the answer and will mark it correct asap, so they don't spent time troubleshooting.

> What really prompted me to ask this question was the growing
>   propensity to get into arguments or at times rationalize something
>   that cannot or shouldn't be. A trend mostly seen in newer users.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971631/convert-an-enum-to-liststring) see the conversation at the end of that answer. See how I put out the fire, you should try the same.

> I am know to be sarcastic in my comments at times (I am that in real
>   life too). But never caustic or personal!!

Deleted answers are visible mods and comments too. Try not to write any comments unless directly related to the question. Being sarcastic isn't helping anyone, unless its really funny. When you get personally insulted simply flag the comment for moderator attention.

> I normally leave a comment when I downvote / vote to close a question.
>   Should I stop doing this for fear of getting obnoxious replies from
>   authors.

If you're getting obnoxious replies from authors you probably aren't writing the nicest comments.

> What is the general practice followed by the more tenured users in
>   such cases?

Take a look at Jon Skeets activity, he is always ultra polite - even to the biggest newbie's.

Comment: In this case, when I said _obnoxious replies_, it wasn't really directed to me or my comment. Although, that has happened in the past. Regardless, I am generally a helpful person even when I am not the one posting a solution. If I can guide someone to a possible solution, I generally do it in the nicest of way. I am not sarcastic 24/7 you know. ;-)

Comment: The whole point is, the newer users don't even bother browsing a bit and seeing how questions are asked. Nor do they bother reading the FAQ's. I have commented on several occasions to new user's posts asking them to read the FAQ's and have had rude replies to that. Something like: _If you don't know the answer, don't waste my time with useless comments like this one._ I flag them, take a step back and just leave the post alone in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with people asking and answering their own questions *provided the quality is maintained in both the question and the answer*.

I've seen a few of these now where the answer was good, but the question was... sub-optimal (the answer got up voted and the question down voted). In cases like this the question runs the same risk as it always does of attracting negative attention - the fact that it is self answered is no excuse.

> But is there a line where we draw a line on what borders on users treating it like their personal blog site

In principal there is nothing wrong with people treating the site as a kind of pseudo blog site (by providing self-answers) if the quality is maintained.

> I normally leave a comment when I downvote / vote to close a question.

That's nice, but you shouldn't feel compelled to do so. I've voted to close almost 700 questions, leaving a comment on each would have been tiresome.

> Should I stop doing this for fear of getting obnoxious replies from authors or even retaliation downvotes

Once you cast that vote your name will be displayed on the close notice, leaving a comment is not necessarily going to save you from revenge down voting.

Comment: See now this makes sense. I am not averse to user posting solutions to their own answers. I have done it on a couple of occasions in the past too. But my intention was never to get some rep out of it. I just find it strange in cases likes the example or when users post a solution within a few minutes of asking one. Then it makes me doubt their intentions. Also, I am not concerned about down votes. They will happen anyway. Serial downvotes will be reversed anyway.